# JFreechart XYline connect with database

Tags: java, jfreechart, linechart, linegraph

I created a graph with connection to the database as follows:

```
String s = jTSensor.getText();
String query="select date, dew_point from records where idSensor like '"+s+"'";
JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset (
    CriaConexao.getConexao(),query);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
    "Records", "Date", "Dew Point", dataset, 
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, true);
BarRenderer renderer = null;
CategoryPlot plot= null;
renderer=new BarRenderer();
ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Records", chart);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(400,650);
```

But only gives a line to show. I wish it was possible to seek other data to the database and show the results with other lines, but I'm not succeeding. Someone can help me please.

Greetings

Comment: "[NOTE](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html): Many people have found this class too restrictive in general use. For the greatest flexibility, please consider writing your own code to read data from a ResultSet and populate a `DefaultCategoryDataset` directly."

Answer (score 1):

Look at [How to display line graph using JFreeChart in jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665222/how-to-display-line-graph-using-jfreechart-in-jsp?rq=1) and build your solution around `createXYLineChart`. For database access there is already a `JDBCXYDataset`. `XYDataset` supports multiple series of data while the `CategoryDataset` you are useing does not (as far as I know).